# CSS: Table border attribute overriden

Tags: html, css

My table border is not showing. After inspecting, I found out that it was overid by a CSS rule. Any idea how can I avoid this ? (PS : I want to keep using the table border attribute)

HTML :

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
* { 
border: 0; 
}
```

PS : I can't know the border value in advance. Its added/configured in an editor (CKEditor).. Thats why I need to way to make the table border attribute more prioritized than CSS rule.

Comment: can you add classes to the elements? If so i would remove the *{ border:0;} and add a class like .borderless {border: 0;} and add that to the elements where the border: 0 is needed. That might be a bit mroe work but its a workaround

Comment: You can't make HTML attributes more prioritized than CSS rules. You'll have to change the CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Just add CSS (with border) for table.

**CSS Specificity**:
The issues is when there are multiple CSS rules, which one to execute is inferenced by browser by help of "CSS Specificity". As '*' has minimum-value, so adding any CSS for element/class/id, etc. will always override it. Its simple.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

```css
* {border: 0;}
```

```html
<table style="border:2px solid black" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't know the border value in advance. (Its added/configured in an editor CKEditor).. Thats why I need to way to make the table border attribute more prioritized.

Comment: I have updated my answer, in that case writing `border=2` as html-attribute will not work. You need to update CSS properties properly (like inline styling). You cannot override one CSS with another HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the table td,th style.

```
td, th {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't know the border value in advance. (Its added/configured in an editor CKEditor).. Thats why I need to way to make the table border attribute more prioritized than CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Add **border** to `table` element

```
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

> **[`border-collapse:collpase;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)** - The border-collapse CSS property sets whether cells inside a  have shared or separate borders.

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<table border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
            <td style="background-color:#dddddd; border-color:#330033">Test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```